# Write a simple program to solve (x3 - 17x + 12 = 0) by direct substitution

Tags: excel, vba

Like the title says, I need to write a simple program to solve (x3 - 17x + 12 = 0) by direct substitution. Can someone explain to me what this even means? I was under the impression that direct substitution required a Y component of some kind? Not really looking for code help, just the logic of it, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible implementation of Pieter's answer.

We can re-write this equation as:

[image]

We put an initial value for **x** in **A1** and in **A2** we put:

```
=(A1^3+12)/17
```

and copy down *(earch row is an iteration on the row above)*
To see how close **A2** is to the actual answer in **B2** we put:

```
=A2^3-17*A1+12
```

and copy down.  Here is a sample with **1** in **A1**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function being solved (by direct substitution) is

```
f: x -> x^3 - 17x + 12
```

and the value being solved for is 0,

so the equation to be solved is what you have posted. You will repeatedly substitute values for x, and evaluate the function value *f(x)* until you obtain a value of zero.